# Show the stable age structure

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Considering the population process described by

where $γ$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $L$ $l$ denotes the survival function of the Leslie matrices and $L$ is the Leslie matrix below

We are trying to prove $v$ is the stable age structure, I think this means it is the eigen vector corresponding with the dominant eigen value, however I'm unsure of how to find the eigenvectors in this general form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the eigenvector that satisfies
$$
(L-\gamma I)v=0,
$$
where $L$ is given, $\gamma$ is the dominant eigenvalue, $I$ is the identity matrix.

In coordinates, you have
$$
(b_1-\gamma)v_1+b_2v_2+\ldots+b_\omega v_\omega=0\\
s_1v_1-\mu v_2=0\\
s_2v_2-\mu v_3=0\\
\ldots\\
s_{\omega-1}v_{\omega-1}-\mu v_\omega=0.
$$
Due to the fact that the eigenvector is determined up to a constant multiplier, you can put $v_1=1$ and solve for all other $v_i$. You will find
$$
v=(1,\gamma^{-1}s_1,\gamma^{-2}s_1s_2,\ldots,\gamma^{\omega-1}s_1s_2\ldots s_{\omega-1}).
$$
The stable age structure is given by
$$
\frac{v}{\sum_i v_i}.
$$